# long delays after animations play

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a Roblox Doors fan-game and everytime I open a door, it spawns a new room. I dont want to spawn all the rooms at once because that lags out mobile. Is there any way of me fixing this 1-2 second lag spike?

*the spawning new room is in the room generation code*

---

Here is my code for the room generation:

```lua
local rooms = 10
local roomsF = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Rooms")
local roomsA = roomsF:GetChildren()
local alreadyRooms = workspace:WaitForChild("Rooms")

function spawnRoom()
    local selectedRoom = math.random(1, #roomsA)
    local chosenRoom = roomsF:WaitForChild("Room"..tostring(selectedRoom))

    local newRoom = chosenRoom:Clone()
    local newDoor = game.ReplicatedStorage.DefaultDoor:Clone()
    local inGameRooms = alreadyRooms:GetChildren()

    newRoom.Name = tostring(#inGameRooms + 1)
    newRoom.Parent = alreadyRooms
    newRoom:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(alreadyRooms:WaitForChild(#inGameRooms).EndPoint.CFrame)

    if newRoom:FindFirstChild("Spawn") then
        newRoom:FindFirstChild("Spawn"):Fire()
    end

    newDoor.Model.DoorNumber.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = #inGameRooms + 1
    newDoor.Number.Value = #inGameRooms + 1
    newDoor.Parent = newRoom
    newDoor:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(alreadyRooms:WaitForChild(#inGameRooms).EndPoint.CFrame)

    newDoor.Collision.Touched:Once(function(part)
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent) or game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent.Parent)

        if player then
            spawnRoom()
            newRoom:FindFirstChild("DoorOpened"):Fire()
        end
    end)
end

spawnRoom()
```

And the code for my door:

```lua
local GameData = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.GameData)

wait(2)

script.Parent.Collision.Touched:Once(function(part)
    
    task.wait(0.1)
    
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent) or game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent.Parent)
    
    local allDoors = workspace.Rooms:GetChildren()
    local nextDoorNumber = script.Parent.Number.Value + 1
    local nextDoor = allDoors[nextDoorNumber].DefaultDoor

    GameData.SetCurrentDoor(script.Parent, script.Parent.Number.Value)
    GameData.SetNextDoor(nextDoor, nextDoorNumber)
    
    -- ANIMATE
    
    local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
    local door = script.Parent.Model
    local doorHinge = door.PrimaryPart
    local doorOpen = TweenInfo.new(0.5, Enum.EasingStyle.Quad, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, 0, false, 0)

    local doorCFrame = TweenService:Create(doorHinge, doorOpen, {
        CFrame = doorHinge.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(100), 0,0)--Change 100 to whatever value. Range of swing.
    })

    local doorCFrameClosed = TweenService:Create(doorHinge, doorOpen, {
        CFrame = doorHinge.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0), 0,0)--Change 100 to whatever value. Range of swing.
    })

    doorCFrame:Play()
    wait(20)--Door Stays Open this long
    doorCFrameClosed:Play()
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `task.wait()` and it fixed the big lag spike